# Recursion ceiling and radicals of integers

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Given $n,k\in\mathbb Z$ what is the minimum $r$ needed such that following iteration is $\leq2$?

$$n_0=n$$
$$n_1=\lceil n_0^{1/k}\rceil$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n_{i+1}=\lceil n_i^{1/k}\rceil$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n_r\leq2$$

> What is the gap $r-\frac{\log_2\log_2 n}{\log_2k}$?

Comment: If $n_{r-1}\geq 2$ you have $n_{r-1}^{1/k}>1$ and thus $n_r\geq 2.$ It is not possible to make $n_r<2.$ You can get $n_r=2,$ however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n_0\le 2$ then $r=0$, so we assume that $n_0\ge 3$.

If $k\le 0$ then $n_1\le 2$ and $r=1$, so we assume that $k\ge 1$.

If $k=1$, then $n_1=n_0$ and $n_i$ newer is not bigger than $2$, so we assume that $k\ge 1$.

By an  induction with respect to $j$ we can check that $n_r\le 2$ iff $n_{r-j}\le 2^{k^j}$ for each $j$. Thus $2^{k^{r-1}}<n_0\le 2^{k^r}$ that is $r=\lceil \log_k \log_2 n\rceil$ and the gap is less than $1$.